# text within div not in proper alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftIxL.png)i'm printing customer details from db within div class,
when i type within the div, the text slightly appears in top

my code

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label">Customer Name & Address </label>
 <div class="col-md-3">sasikumar </div>
</div>
```

i expect output to be in proper alignment, i don't know what's the issue with this line. any solutions please

Comment: sasikumar is the text?

Comment: yes brother @godfather

Comment: do you have a css doc?

Comment: are you using css for this?

Comment: yes i've css doc @Matt-the-Marxist

Comment: can we see it? we cant help blind

Comment: i think your using flex?

Comment: no i'm using bootstrap @godfather

Comment: try this .form-group{display:flex;}

Comment: it's not working and affects responsive too

Comment: can you edit the question to include the css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use like this code:-

```css
.middle{display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;margin:0;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-group">
<label class="title middle">Customer Name & Address </label>
 <div class="cls_value middle">sasikumar </div>
</div>
```